# xcode ARC conversion error [CFString retain] crash

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I converted my huge IOS program to ARC using xcode auto conversion. After that I am getting the following error:
[CFString retain]: message sent to deallocated instance

The trace shows the following line where it crashed:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:tile.imagePath];
```

Next line in the trace gives:__arclite_objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue at /SourceCache/arclite/arclite-7.1/source/arclite.m:241

Can someone suggest me where I can look further, or what can I do to remove this crash?

Thanks a lot

EDIT: Looks like the (NSString *)p initialization in the code below needs some changes.  How should I change it, so that the tile.imagePath doesn't become null?

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(MKMapRect)f path:(NSString *)p{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        imagePath = p;
        frame = f;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Whatever tile is, it ain't alive, memory-management-wise.

Comment: Thanks CodaFi.  the object tile is from an NSMutable array tiles. When I dig back, I notice that the tiles is initiated as follows: tiles = [NSMutableArray array];  Does this make a problem?  (I can see no alloc).  But it was a working code and ARC did not change code here.

Comment: Well, no.  Actually, before ARC, that +array method returned an autoreleased instance, but now, it's just short lived.  Use alloc and init instead and NSLog it to make sure it's alive.

Comment: NSLog shows that the 'tiles' mutable array exists. I can print out the tile frame.  But the tile.imagePath crashes.  imagePath is initialized as: NSString *path = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@.png", tileBase, tileKey];
                ImageTile *tile = [[ImageTile alloc] initWithFrame:frame path:path];    I am not sure what the ImageTile type is (inherited code:-).  It is to display overlay tiles over SKmap. What might be wrong in the initialization for 'path'?

Comment: Looks like `[-ImageTile initWithFrame:path:]` doesn't retain `path`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`imagePath` is probably a `__unsafe_unretained` iVar (or maybe you're seeing `weak` or `assign`). Change it to `strong` so that it is retained by ARC.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes imagePath was declared as __Unsafe_undefined and issue resolved when I changed to strong.

Comment: Please note: it's __unsafe_**unretained**, not undefined. This tells you what the problem was: it wasn't retained (same as `assign` before ARC).