# [CFString retain]: message sent to deallocated

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management

I enabled zombies with my Xcode to find if my process crashes to a memory leak. Here is a code snippet:

```
- (NSString *)facVersion
{
    return facVersion;
}


- (void) setFacVersion:(NSString*)_facVersion
{
    if(facVersion != nil) [facVersion release];
    facVersion = [_facVersion retain];
}
```

Now when I call

```
NSLog(@"%@", facVersion);
[self setFacVersion:facVersion];
```

the code crashes with the message

> [CFString retain]: message sent to deallocated

Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: This has helped me for ARC : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10596942/3411787

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a typical problem with badly written setters. When the object itself is the last owner of the backing ivar of the property, assigning the property to itself causes a release effectively deallocating the object, then a retain on the same deallocated object. You can fix this in two ways. Either check for the to-be-assigned object not being the same as the current value of the property, or retain first and release only after. All in all, solution one:

```
- (void) setFacVersion:(NSString*)_facVersion
{
    if (facVersion == _facVersion) return;
    [facVersion release];
    facVersion = [_facVersion retain];
}
```

Soltion two:

```
- (void) setFacVersion:(NSString*)_facVersion
{
    [_facVersion retain];
    [facVersion release];
    facVersion = _facVersion;
}
```

By the way, checking for an object not being `nil` before releasing it is superfluous. Objective-C is not Java.

Answer (score 1):

It's supposed to be `if (facVersion != _facVersion)` in the setter. Otherwise if you set the same object again, your setter will release it (resulting in the object being deallocated) and you can't use it (retain) after that:

```
- (void) setFacVersion:(NSString*)_facVersion
{
    if(facVersion != _facVersion) {
        [facVersion release];
        facVersion = [_facVersion retain];
    }
}
```

Also, did you know about [Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)?

> Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) is a compiler feature that provides
>   automatic memory management of Objective-C objects. Rather than having
>   to think about about retain and release operations, ARC allows you to
>   concentrate on the interesting code, the object graphs, and the
>   relationships between objects in your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the same object to `setFacVersion` as already set, it will first release it and then try to retain released (and deallocated) object.

Answer (score 0):

You're releasing it before you call retain.

Unless you're comparing the pointers before releasing and retaining, you should use something like:

```
- (void) setFacVersion:(NSString*)_facVersion
    [_facVersion retain];
    [facVersion release];
    facVersion = _facVersion;
}
```

That way, if the pointers are the same, as you demonstrated, you won't get a crash.

Or just let the compiler synthesize the setter for you.