# [CFString retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7020100

Tags: ios

I am converting an existing project to ARC. It is converting some of the variables to __unsafe_unretained.
My application is crashing with a message [CFString retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7020100. As my application is huge , it is crashing with this message in every flow. Can anybody suggest a generic solution to this.

Comment: This has helped me for ARC : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10596942/3411787