# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when saving parentContext

Tags: ios, core-data, exc-bad-access

Alright, I have a piece of code that queries everything from an entity in CoreData, cycles through them all, processes the data, appends it to an array then deletes the CoreData object.

Saving the current context works just fine, but calling save on the `parentContext` gives me a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error.

Here's my code:

In my init method:

```
managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
managedObjectContext.parentContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
```

Essentially taking the main `managedObjectContext` and setting it as my `parentContext`. So far, no problem.

```
managedObjectContext.performBlock({ () -> Void in
    do {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Changes")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id BEGINSWITH[c] %@", idPrefix)

        if let changes = try self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [Changes] {
            for change in changes {
                let json = change.json!
                let newJson = change.newJson!
                let changeId = change.id!

                self.managedObjectContext.deleteObject(change)

                let deserializedJson = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(json.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, options: [])
                let deserializedNewJson = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(newJson.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, options: [])

                updates.append([
                    "Id": changeId,
                    "NewJson": deserializedNewJson,
                    "Json": deserializedJson
                ])
            }

            try self.managedObjectContext.save()

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                do {
                    try self.managedObjectContext.parentContext?.save()
                }
                catch {
                    completionHandler(error: error as NSError)
                }
            })
        }
    }
    catch {
        completionHandler(error: error as NSError)
    }
})
```

I enabled `NSZombies` to see of I could get more relevant information. When I try to execute the save of the `parentContext` on the main thread, I get the following error:

```
*** -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1579a0570
```

I have run into instances where this actually goes through without a problem, but most of the time, I get the error I just mentioned above.

Any ideas would be more than welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out that the problem was because I had a Core Data property that started with "new". I changed the name of my property and all is fixed.

All explained here: [[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065536/cfstring-release-message-sent-to-deallocated-instance/19093455#comment58547033_19093455)